# Backbone fetch success and error function issue

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've a fetch method on a collection. The callback function success and error is never called but the fetch happens correctly and fill the collection. It seems very strange.

```
var TweetsCollection= new Tweets();
TweetsCollection.fetch({
     success:function (tweets){<---never called
   alert("ok");
 },
 error:function(c){<---never called

    alert("ko");

 }




});
console.log(TweetsCollection);<---- collection correctly filled
```

and this is the fetch methof od TweetsCollection:

```
fetch: function(options) {

var collection = this; 
var params = {
user_id: this.query,
page:this.page
};


 cb.__call(
"statuses_userTimeline",
params,
  function (reply) {
// console.log(reply);
  collection.reset(reply);
// return reply;

  }
 );


 }
```

Comment: where have you defined cb?Please share more code

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to override the fetch method. 
If you want to add extra logic to the sync process, you override the sync method.